# how do i pass my c# variable in external.js file

Tags: javascript, c#

**Aspx:**

```
 public string firstName = "Manas";
```

**external.js:**

```
var value = '<%=firstName%>';
alert(value);
```

I am not seeing my expected output

Comment: You'll need to configure Razor to parse `.js` files (if it's even possible?)

Comment: you can't access the server variable in js file. check my answer

Comment: store it as a session variable and then access it using js..

Comment: how can we do by session variable , can any one explain detail by short code , am new to this need a help

Comment: @jaffer, have you tried the solution ?

Comment: @Venkatraman i got an out put ,by following you

Comment: @jaffer, what issue is still exist to accept an answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include it as Inline script in the `.aspx` file. it applies to any server script file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var firstName = '<%=firstName%>';

  or

  localStorage.setItem('firstName', '<%=firstName%>');
</script>
```

Try to access localStorage value in external file like below or anywhere.

```
localStorage.getItem('firstName');
```

Comment: am getting out put if i do like this , my doubt is about is it possible if i give this code:    var value = '<%=firstName%>'; alert(value);  on external.js  .

Comment: you can access this variable in your external file as window.firstName. only this u need to include your external after this script

Comment: Be wary of this. It can cause big problems if your `firstname` value include a quote.

Comment: escaping  to  html entity will be  a right one with the same solution